# Monitor data usage per connected (individual) wifi

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, wifi-hotspot, data-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor data usage by individuals (connected wifi)   from my Android WLAN hotspot.

After enabling hotspot, It shows me no. of users connected and provides a feature to block individuals. But I want to check or monitor how much data is being used by individuals. I'm also interested in watching/monitoring bandwidth (transfer speed)  being used by individuals (connected wifi).

Is there any way or app available which can do this job?

Comment: Not sure about the "by individual data usage", but the closest I could find in [my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_finder#group_1081) was the [Data Sharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awake.datasharing) app. Natively, there's nothing coming even close AFAIK. [Portable Wifi Hotspot Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bcorp.hotspotmanager) claims to meet all your requirements – no guarantees, though :)

Comment: PS: [MobWifi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=beavanchua.com.mobwifi) could be your candidate. Calculates "per session", but from the app description it's not clear whether that means "client session" or "global hotspot session". In the app comments, the dev responded to the question "How do i know how much cost per user." with "MobWifi provides a receipt for the data usage per session." So it seems to fit.

Comment: @Izzy Data sharing shows total hotspot usage activity for present time, daily and monthly usges. It detects users, displays their MAC and IP address but doesn't show individual data usage - Good application though. Mobwifi doesn't detect even connected users mostly. Portable Wifi Hotspot Manager's claims are not right.

Comment: Thanks for testing and reporting back! I'm curious whether something suitable turns up. Please ping me in case it does!